# Reverse PowerPC's rlwinm

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, powerpc

I'm currently looking into understanding and modifying some source code for a game mod I found. At start some adjustments are made by using this:

`rlwinm r3, r3, 0, 29, 25`

I'm now trying to find a way to reverse this very adjustment later on in the game - so I don't want to remove it from the game completely, just make it reversible when certain conditions are met.

What's the assembly command for reversing the change this line did?

Answer (score 3):

[`rlwinm` (Rotate Left Word Immediate Then AND with Mask)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=is-rlwinm-rlinm-rotate-left-word-immediate-then-mask-instruction) includes an AND, so some of the original information is gone.  You'll have to save the original `r3` value somewhere so you can restore it later.

As a simpler example, consider `and reg, 0x0f`.  The information necessary to undo it (the state of the higher bits) is gone, since the destination and source are the same register so the source was overwritten with the modified value.

And yes, this `rlwinm` does zero some bits; the bit-range for the mask doesn't keep all 32 bits and *only* rotate.  In fact the shift (rotate) count is `0`, the first immediate operand in the asm source syntax.  So it's just using it for an immediate AND.  It's doing something like `r3 &= ~0x0000003c`, `(1<<(31-25)) -  (1<<(31-29))` since IBM numbers bits backwards, with MSB=0 and LSB=31 or 63 depending on operand-size!

I may have an off-by-one in one or both of the mask-begin and mask-end immediates; I didn't read the docs super carefully, but `0x3c` or `~0x3c` seems like a plausible mask value.  I think it's actually clearing a few bits and keeping the rest since mask-begin is higher than mask-end. So `~0x3c`.  Unless that bit-field is saved elsewhere so you could restore it with a rotate-and-insert, it doesn't really matter exactly what masking this `rlwinm` is doing, just that it's a non-reversible operation.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. From what I understood, `rlwinm` is ireversible so I need to save the original value. I'm quite new to Assembly - how would I save the value of r3 beforehands and restore it later on?

Comment: @Moldevort: In another register if "later" is only a few instructions later, or in memory somewhere if it might be after this function returns.  But since PowerPC is a RISC machine, you'll need another registers as a pointer to static storage; `sw` doesn't have room for a full 32-bit address.  If there's already a pointer to somewhere in `.data` or `.bss` in another register when this code runs, you could `sw` relative to that if there's spare space (left unused for alignment padding perhaps) anywhere within +- a few KiB of that location.

Comment: What's the command to store the value of r3 to a new register and replacing the value of r3 with the old one later on?

Comment: @Moldevort: If you don't know how to copy one register to another, read a PowerPC tutorial.  I barely know that ISA myself, mostly just from reading compiler output sometimes.  (But I know asm for a few other ISAs much better, so for me it's just different names for the same concepts.  That's why I'm describing concepts I know will work, but not using names of specific instructions.  I think PowerPC might use `mv` for `mov`, and I think `sw` / `lw` are store-word / load-word, but check a tutorial for the operand and addressing-mode syntax.)

Comment: @Moldevort You seem to be way out of your depth.  I agree with Peter Cordes and recommend starting with an assembly tutorial.  If you don't learn the basics of assembly programming, whatever it is that you attempt to do will certainly be going nowhere useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes
I have read some tutorials and couldn't a find a one that seems to bring all necessary information together with specific examples (instead of describing with many many words and technical terms). I will look into it - thank you both of you.